# Deviances in H2O

Tags: deviance, h2o

does anyone know how exactly the Deviances (Poisson, Gamma, Tweedie) are computed in H2O? I cannot find the functions. For interpretation purposes I would like to know the calculations.

Thank you!

Comment: It's defined in here: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-algos/src/main/java/hex/glm/GLMMetricBuilder.java but it's still not clear to me what the explicit formula is

Answer (score 2):

The formulas are in the [H2O User Guide](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/index.html) in the [GLM section](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/glm.html).  Here are links for the deviance formulas for

1. [Linear](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/glm.html#linear-regression-gaussian-family): $$D=\sum^{N}_{i=1}{(y_{i}-\hat{y}_{i})^{2}}$$
2. [Logistic](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/glm.html#logistic-regression-binomial-family): $$-D=\sum^{N}_{i=1}{\left(y_{i}\log{(\hat{y}_{i})}+(1-y_{i})\log{(1-\hat{y}_{i})}\right)}$$
3. [Poisson](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/glm.html#poisson-models): $$D=-2\sum^{N}_{i=1}{\left(y_{i}\log{\left(\frac{y_{i}}{\hat{y}_{i}}\right)}-\left(y_{i}-\hat{y}_{i}\right)\right)}$$
4. [Gamma](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/glm.html#gamma-models): $$D=2\sum^{N}_{i=1}{\left(-\log{\left(\frac{y_{i}}{\hat{y}_{i}}\right)}+\frac{\left(y_{i}-\hat{y}_{i}\right)}{\hat{y}_{i}}\right)}$$
5. [Tweedie](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/glm.html#tweedie-models): where $p\neq1$ and $p\neq2$ $$D=-2\sum^{N}_{i=1}{\left(\frac{y_{i}\left(y_{i}^{1-p}-\hat{y}_{i}^{1-p}\right)}{1-p}-\frac{\left(y_{i}^{2-p}-\hat{y}_{i}^{2-p}\right)}{2-p}\right)}$$

Note for Tweedie there is an error in the docs,  you can see the formula actually used in the h2o source, line 395 here: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-algos/src/main/java/hex/glm/GLMModel.java. The formula in this answer shows the correct formula rather than the formula in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

The deviance equations in H2O should be following the general specifications used typically in actuarial sciences. See for instance [Modern Actuarial Risk Theory](https://fac.ksu.edu.sa/sites/default/files/modern_acturial_risk_theory.pdf) by Kaas et al. page $308$ for the Tweedie Deviance and pages $246$ and $247$ for Poisson and Gamma Deviances. They correspond to the same equations in the accepted answer above, save the weights.